# Implicit declaration of SecKeyRawVerify?

Tags: c, macos, cryptography, commoncrypto

I've been trying to resolve why I get this warning when using SecKeyRawVerify:

```
implicit declaration of function 'SecKeyRawVerify'
```

I've looked in the CommonCrypto header files, but this does not appear to be there, other than in the open source code online.

The function itself works fine and behaves as I expect, and as far as I understand this is the proper way do verify an RSA signature with CommonCrypto.

What exactly am I missing, why is this function not declared in a header?

Comment: Are you calling `SecRawKeyVerify` or `SecKeyRawVerify`?

Comment: Only the latter exists. If you're trying to use the former, you should get this warning, although the warning will have the name you used, not the correct name.

Comment: er oops @Barmar, always confuse the order of that